# Java Iterator over elements that meets conditions

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I want to know if is possible to filter a HashSet to just return the items that matches *country* with a given string without modifiying the original set.

```
public class Coin
        private final String country;
        [...]


public class CoinSet
    HashSet<Coin> coins = new HashSet();
    coins.iterator(String filterString);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s for that:

```
Set<Coin> filteredSet = coins.stream()
                .filter(coin -> filterString.equals(coin.getCountry()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```